# how to rotate a vector around an arbitrary axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I have an axis, as defined by 2 vectors, for example one that points upwards at `x = 10`:

```
const axisStart = new Vector3(10, 0, 0)
const axisEnd = new Vector3(10, 0, 1)
```

I'm getting the normalized axis direction like so:

```
const axisDirection = new Vector3().subVectors(axisEnd, axisStart).normalize()
```

**How can I rotate a vector** (e.g. `Vector3(50, 0, 0)`) **around my original axis**?

I've tried using `Vector3.applyAxisAngle(axisDirection , radians)`, but because the axis has been normalized, the rotation happens around the world center (0, 0) and not around the axis' original position.

Comment: You'll need to move it to the origin before the rotation and then move it back afterwards. Subtract `axisStart` from the vector you're rotating, do your rotation as usual, then add `axisStart` to the vector you're rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by finding the exact point on the axis around which the point rotates, using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905533/find-perpendicular-distance-from-point-to-line-in-3d) and translating the pseudocode from it into typescript:

```
getPivotPoint(pointToRotate: Vector3, axisStart: Vector3, axisEnd: Vector3) {
    const d = new Vector3().subVectors(axisEnd, axisStart).normalize()
    const v = new Vector3().subVectors(pointToRotate, axisStart)
    const t = v.dot(d)
    const pivotPoint = axisStart.add(d.multiplyScalar(t))
    return pivotPoint
  }
```

Then, as @Ouroborus pointed out, I can then translate the point, apply the rotation, and translate it back:

```
rotatePointAroundAxis(pointToRotate: Vector3, axisStart: Vector3, axisEnd, radians: number) {
    const axisDirection = new Vector3().subVectors(axisEnd, axisStart).normalize()
    const pivotPoint = getPivotPoint(pointToRotate, axisStart, axisEnd)
    const translationToWorldCenter = new Vector3().subVectors(pointToRotate, pivotPoint)
    const translatedRotated = translationToWorldCenter.clone().applyAxisAngle(axisDirection, radians)
    const destination = pointToRotate.clone().add(translatedRotated).sub(translationToWorldCenter)
    return destination
  }
```

The above code is working nicely, leaving it here for my future self and for other who might find this useful.